# if query returning a return error laravel

Tags: laravel, if-statement

I need some help with this query, I don't understand why am I getting this error "`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'return'(T_RETURN)`" even though my previous line was working. I checked on other question similar to this error and see if I have similar mistake but I don't think so, I even double checked to see if I am missing any bracket in my query. Can someone please help me? Thanks a lot.

This part of the code work, "`if(count($data)>0){`" but when I changed to this it doesn't work anymore " `if (hire::where('hire_status','Yes'->count($data) > 0){`"

Controller:

```
     public function getHire(){
        $data['data'] = DB::table('personal_infos')->where('deleted_at',NULL)->get()->sortByDesc('created_at');
        if (hire::where('hire_status','Yes'->count($data) > 0){
       // if(count($data)>0){
        return view('hire',$data);
    }else{
    return view('hire');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing closing parenthesis `)`.

```
if (hire::where('hire_status','Yes'->count($data) > 0){

if (hire::where('hire_status', 'Yes')->count($data) > 0) {
```

Comment: What.. I can't believe i missed that bracket.. even though i checked it.. But thanks a lot for helping me find my mistake

Comment: sorry to disturb you but may i know what this error mean? "Invalid parameter number: mixed named and positional parameters " I got this after adding the bracket @lagbox

Comment: @Dkna sounds like a pdo error where there is a mix of bound parameters as named bindings and regular unnamed bindings in a prepared statement. would need to see more to know what is causing that though